# Wrong answer from DSolve when solving a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 12.0.0, fixed in 12.1.1.**

---

I was trying to solve the following differential equation: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y^2-1 \quad \text{and} \quad y(0)=1$$

and I used the code below:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x^2 - 1, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

The output from *Mathematica 12* is

```
{{y[x] -> 1/(1 - x)}}
```

However, it is obviously wrong because if $y(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, then $$y'(x)=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} \neq \left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)^2+x^2-1$$

I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me (in V12.0).  Also fails on the ode: `DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x^2 - 1}, y, x]`

Comment: Can't reproduce in _v9.0.1_ and _v11.2_. Which version are you in?

Comment: @xzczd 12.0.0.0

Comment: Please report it to Wolfram: http://support.wolfram.com

Comment: @Superfrankie: Interestingly, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+y%5Bx%5D%5E2+%2B+x%5E2+-+1,+y%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+1

Comment: Just to compare: Maple 2018.2 fails with it, producing an error.

Comment: @Slepecky Mamut: Verification FullSimplify[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x^2 - 1, y[0] == 1} /. sol] confirms the solution obtained in 11.3( with y instead of y[x])..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As noted by other users, this is a bug in `DSolve` in Version 12.0.

The problem appears to be related to a change in `Series` between Version 11.3 and Version 12.0, which is under investigation.

A partial workaround for the problem is to set an assumption on the independent variable as shown below to obtain the correct solution.

```
In[1]:= DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x^2 - 1, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x, 
  Assumptions -> x > 0] // InputForm

Out[1]//InputForm=
{{y[x] -> (I*2^(I/2)*x*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*
      ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 - I/2, (-1 + I)*x] + (1 - I)*2^(1/2 + I/2)*x*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*
      Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 - I/2, (-1 + I)*x] + 
     I*x*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 + I/2, 
       (1 + I)*x] + (1 + I)*Sqrt[2]*x*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*
      ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 + I/2, (1 + I)*x] - (1 - I)*2^(I/2)*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*
      Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 - I/2, (-1 + I)*x] + 
     2^(3/2 + I/2)*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*
      ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 - I/2, (-1 + I)*x] - (1 + I)*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*
      Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 + I/2, (1 + I)*x] - 
     2*Sqrt[2]*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*
      ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 + I/2, (1 + I)*x])/
    (2^(I/2)*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*
      ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 - I/2, (-1 + I)*x] - (1 + I)*2^(1/2 + I/2)*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*
      Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 - I/2, (-1 + I)*x] - 
     Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[1/4 + I/4]*Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 + I/2, 
       (1 + I)*x] - (1 - I)*Sqrt[2]*Gamma[1/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 - I/4]*Gamma[3/4 + I/4]*
      ParabolicCylinderD[-1/2 + I/2, (1 + I)*x])}}
```

I apologize for the confusion caused by this issue.

Devendra Kapadia,
Wolfram Research, Inc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work under the assumption $x<0$ though the solution is valid (at least, for small negative values of $x$).

Comment: @user64494 It's because the series is being expanded about (positive) `Infinity`.  The assumption `x < 0` would contradict that and cause `Series` to fail.

Comment: Are there other known consequences of this `Series` bug?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a workaround for this particular case, based on the method shown in [Riccati Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation):

```
Block[{DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`Riccati},
 DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`Riccati[y_[x_], q0_, q1_, q2_, c_] :=
  Module[{R, S, u},
   S = q2*q0;
   R = q1 + D[q2, x]/q2;
   {{y[x] -> -u'[x]/(q2*u[x]) /. 
       First@DSolve[u''[x] - R*u'[x] + S*u[x] == 0, u, x] /. {C[2] -> 
        C[1] c, C[1] -> c}}}
   ];
 sol = DSolve[ivp = {y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x^2 - 1, y[0] == 1}, y, x]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ivp /. sol // FullSimplify
(*  {{True, True}}  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be fixed in 12.1.1, `DSolve` and `DSolveValue` give the same result as in the workarounds posted:

[image: screenshot of notebook]